# Pay pal postback question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

Hope some one can answer my question.

I am developing a web page with a paypal "Buy Now" button. The code for the page is as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
<div id="content">
    @RenderBody()    

    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"  >
    <input type="hidden" name="..." value="..."/>
    <input type="hidden" name="..." value="..."/>
    <input type="image" src="..." border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
    <img alt="" border="0" src="..." width="1" height="1"/>
    </form>    
</div>
<div id="footer2">...</div>

</html>
```

when the user clicks the "Buy Report" button he is taken to a whole new page to paypal web site away from my web site. What I am trying to achieve is when the user clicks the "Buy Report" I want to show the paypal page with in my web page

I am using ASP.NET MVC3. Can it be done? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to put this form inside an iframe if you want the user to stay on your page.

Comment: Thanks @Tejs  for the answer:

For now I am planning to use frames:
I did something like this:
'
    <iframe id="testFrame">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"  >
            <input type="hidden" name="..." value="..."/>
            <input type="hidden" name="..." value="..."/>
            <input type="image" src="..." border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
            <img alt="" border="0" src="..." width="1" height="1"/>
            </form> 
    </iframe>
'
I cannot see the "Buy Report" button at all

Comment: PS: I am not a BIG fan of iFrame. Therefore, would not recommend iFrame.

Comment: PayPal actively rejects (i)frames. Worst case, you could get your account suspended. If you must have it within your own website, purchase Website Payments Pro Hosted (also known as 'Hosted Sole Solution').

Answer (score 2):

I would advise "going with the flow" of PayPal by not using an IFrame. There is a configurable option in PayPal to return to your site also.

Comment: +1 Agreed. "Going with the flow" is a typical flow when dealing with PayPal. Not only is there a configurable option for PayPal to return to your site, but there are configurable options to customize the PayPal page your customers are directed to when they "Buy Now". Using frames appears suspicious.

Comment: +1 for Chase's suggestion. Heads-up: when customizing your page on PayPal, you may need to place your banner in a https-protected images folder on your server :)